# Not able to deploy the google cloud datalab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

While deploying the google cloud datalab, I bump into the following error :

```
    May 18 15:55:50 datalab-deploy-main-20160518-15-41-42 startupscript:ERROR: 
        (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the 
        application code is unhealthy.  (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying).
    May 18 15:55:50 datalab-deploy-main-20160518-15-41-42 startupscript: 
        Step deploy datalab module failed.
```

Can anyone please let me know where I am going wrong. I am following the instructions here https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart

Comment: Posting on behalf of user [ccasimiro9444](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6583557/ccasimiro9444) who has left a comment as an answer; _I  can't comment, so will write here. Please write what commands you wrote to get there._